# Azure DevOps GIT (gitflow) how to enforce pull request on develop branch an keep origin up-to-date?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm trying to implement a gitflow like workflow in my Azure DevOps hosted git repo. I've enabled CI/CD to my QA server that triggers from completion of pull request targeting the develop branch. 
Also, in ado, I've enabled pull request branch policy on develop so feature branches cannot be directly merged without a PR and code review. 
This all works except when pull request are completed they are leaving origin/develop behind local develop.

So right now if I:
`git checkout develop`
I see this message:
`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 11 commits.`

So, under normal circumstances I think the fix for this is:
`git push` or `git push origin` -- from the develop branch.

But since there is a branch policy in force that requires a pull request, I cannot push. When I try to push develop, I get this message:
`! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.)`
Well, okay, I've done 11 pull requests to this branch already.
Any idea how to fix this?

Pull requests targeting develop should leave origin in sync with local.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments I have disabled the branch policy that forces pull requests. Then I did a git push to clean up the situation. But here is the log from develop as requested below:

```
>git log
commit 545319a657801f3c279f727c53aa7d5b9d9f9d6e (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
Merge: fe89f0a dad0fa3
Author: Ken Hadden <khadden@mycompany.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 28 18:09:32 2019 -0700

    Merge branch 'master' into develop

commit fe89f0af4a9fe3848880854dbd88e3980e81bdb4
Merge: 9b37a92 c7fe732
Author: Ken Hadden <khadden@mycompany.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 28 12:15:48 2019 -0700

    Merge branch 'develop' of https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/mycompany/_git/mycompany into develop

commit c7fe7329df9d40d0ed6db0ddf9f46ab5173aab85 (tag: 201)
Merge: 2386bbe c3b8468
Author: Ken Hadden <khadden@mycompany.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 25 20:50:07 2019 +0000

    Merged PR 7: Build from PR test 3

commit 9b37a9238f369d0fd939b15446e2598a4b984cda
Merge: d3e27c1 c3b8468
Author: Ken Hadden <khadden@mycompany.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 25 13:41:12 2019 -0700

    test 5

commit c3b8468f49d6426469699dcc19c01fc183823355
Author: Ken Hadden <khadden@mycompany.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 25 13:39:45 2019 -0700

    test 4

commit d3e27c1b6abba1e0978a0c2673ebf5969ced37a0
Merge: 0415cf7 2386bbe
Author: Ken Hadden <khadden@mycompany.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 25 13:37:37 2019 -0700

    Merge branch 'develop' of https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/mycompany/_git/mycompany into develop

commit 0415cf7f790770b9bc9e672a5998e85b0815ed46
Merge: 2ef8b41 6dc753e
Author: Ken Hadden <khadden@mycompany.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 25 13:34:27 2019 -0700

    test 4

commit 6dc753eda1697b84a679d6105d2ef18a7f1d3043
:
```

Comment: Can you share the `git log` of local `develop` branch and the remote branch?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk log attached to op.

Comment: I see you disabled the branch policies and you pushed to develop, but you shouldn't commit to your local develop, if you have branch policies to this branch, you should commit locally only to other branches and use the Pull Request.

Comment: In Azure DevOps, pull request only seem to work with the remote branches. I.e. if I have a feature branch I need to commit the feature branch to remote (origin) in order get Azure DevOps to see the branch and have it available in the "Create Pull Request" screen. I'm missing something in this workflow. It shouldn't be this hard to use.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is similar to the ones of @shayki Abramczyk and @Ken Hadden. What works for us is:

```bsh
develop>
develop> git checkout -b feature/my-cool-new-feature
feature/my..> "Hello" > newfile.txt
feature/my..> git add -A
feature/my..> git commit -m "Add newfile.txt"
feature/my..> git push -u origin HEAD
```

Then I go to pull requests in Azure Devops and I get the option to create a PR out of my new branch that shows up there. When created, if I set it to auto-complete, then when it has been approved, built and tested ok it merges automatically to the target branch (in your case develop).

When "A-DOPS" is done, back at my machine I do:

```bsh
feature/my..> git checkout develop
develop> git pull
```

And my local develop is in sync with the remote.

Comment: Okay, yea, this makes sense. I need to re-enable the branch policies and try it all again this way. It would be nice if ADO had the option to clean up the remote feature branches after PR completion.

Comment: @KenHadden I'm not sure but I think they are cleaned up on the server when a PR is completed. The problem I have is that they are not cleaned up in one's local repository. I had to devise some sketchy scripts to do that. :\